# Is it useful to paint the seams with smear tool?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I have some problems with seams on my model. When I export it to a game engine, some seams are visible, not bad, but I prefer to know if I can paint on "texture paint" to make them less visible?

Is the "smear" tool useful or do I have to restart my texturing work?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how detailed your texture is. The "Smear" tool is a possibility, if you have a low-detail texture. On higher detailed texture maps it would blur out the details which in your case would be for example the hard lines between the red and the brown area on the barrel.

I prefer the Clone Brush. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Leftclick to select the are to be copied from, then simply draw with Leftclick over the seam.

[image: clone brush in action]

Comment: it is look like very simple , even with "clone brush" . thanks.